# InAppPurchases de google, cuenta de merchant?

Tags: android

ando un poco perdido con esto de "merchant account"

Estoy implementando In App Purchases en una app que hice hace un tiempo,todo va bien pero al parecer yo ya tenia una cuenta "merchant" y google **no** me la pidió al momento de añadir productos virtuales en google console.

Entonces me surgen estas preguntas...

- Que es un merchant account?
- Donde puedo acceder la cuenta merchant?
- Donde puedo ver el dinero que he ganado vendiendo esos productos
  virtuales? en que website?
- Como me pagarán? por que no he puesto nada
  para recibir pagos ni nada(o no me acuerdo haber puesto esto)
- Como puedo saber cual cuenta "merchant" está asociada con mis apps?

Gracias de antemano!